# Find all '.c' and '.h' file in directory except in 'test' directories in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to find all the .c and .h files in my directory, excluding the ones in the 'test' folders (there are multiple).

The directory I'm searching has test directories such as:

```
myDirectory/abc/def/test
myDirectory/abc/def/ghi/test
```

etc.

So far, I've tried:

```
find /myDirectory/* -type d -name test -prune -o -name '*.c' -print
```

and this seems to work for the .c files, but when I run:

```
find /myDirectory/* -type d -name test -prune -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -print
```

nothing is returned at all.

How do I include multiple file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group the two `-name` predicates:

```
find /myDirectory/* -type d -name test -prune -o \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -print
```

The backslash is needed to escape the parentheses.

Comment: Huzzah! That did it! Related question: if I want to get rid of all the directories that contain the word 'test', should I do: 

    find /myDirectory/* -type d -name \*test\* -prune -o \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -print

I'm worried I'll end up removing files with 'test' in the name (which I want to keep). Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that should work, however, you need to put `'*test*'` in quotes – otherwise the wildcard ("glob", `*`) will be expanded before `find` can see it.